# Use query.v1 to filter on member groups

Tags: filter, yaml, members, versionone

How can I use query.v1 (in YAML) to filter on Members that belong to a particular member group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal name for MemberGroup is MemberLabel, and you can access the MemberGroups that a member belongs to using the MemberLabels attribute of the Member asset.

Here's a YAML query to filter on the MemberLabels.Name for a MemberGroup named "Developers":

```
from: Member
select:
  - Name
  - Username
where:
  MemberLabels.Name: Developers
```

Alternatively, you could use a Filter statement.